# Customize Record Types 'New' Button of a Standard Object Tab

Tags: record

On clicking the 'Case' Tab, and then the 'New' button,

It asks to choose the 'Record Type' in the next screen. It shows all available recordtypes in the picklist. I want to remove couple of record types from the List. How do I do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the record types from the available types in the users profile. Or you could potentially delete the record types after reviewing the implications including but not limited to (Code dependencies, report dependencies, workflow and validation rule dependencies)

Comment: I want all the profiles to be able to access these record types, by creating a custom link, not thru the Object Tab.